# Register Microsoft Practices Unity container in Unty webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am working on new web api project and using Unity.WebAPI as my DI. I have other projects which uses Microsoft.Practices.Unity as DI and resolving dependencies. I need to use objects from those objects in my web api project. When I try to register their dependencies, I am not able to convert Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer to Unity.WebApi.UnityContainer. I googled and could not achieve the output. Please see my below code reference:

Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    Bootstrapper.Initialise();
    UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    // Other stuffs here
}
```

Bootstrapper.cs

```
public class Bootstrapper
{
    public static void Initialise()
    {
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(CreateContainer()));
    }
    
    public static Unity.IUnityContainer CreateContainer()
    {
        Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer container = RegisterMyDependencies();
        return (Unity.IUnityContainer)container;
        // suspicious cast: there is no type in the solution which is inherited from both 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer'
        // and 'Unity.UnityContainer'
    }
}
```

So, my controller is not resolving the dependencies. I understand that somewhere I am not making a communication between two libraries. I am new to this unity DI and not sure on how to resolve this issue. I tried using Unity package, it did not work as for web api project, we need to use Unity.WebApi. Appreciate if someone help me out on this.

Comment: Consider creating a wrapper class that implements both interfaces while delegating to a private Unity Web API container in its implementation

Comment: thanks @AluanHaddad, would you mind bit explain on this or can you refer any link on how to achieve. Sorry for not getting your point.

Comment: I don't want to write an example because I don't know the ins and outs of unity's ioc but I'm simply suggesting that you write a wrapper class that implements the required interface. The wrapper class can delegate its functionality to an instance of the actual container you want to use